# Ractive UI commands with button binding

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have a simple WPF application:

View:

```
...
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="D0" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </Grid>
...
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
   public ICommand MyCommand { get; }

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => {});
   }
}
```

**Problem:** When I click on the button or press D0 key I have '*The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*' exception. But in case if I remove the button and press on D0 it's OK and command successfully completes. And there is the same result with the async command.

How should I bind this command to my button or what I do wrong?

Comment: That message often suggests that you are trying to access object created on UI thread from thread other than UI thread.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown? Please provide a reproducible sample or at least explain what you are doing in your code. You should not get this exception using the code you have posted.